# Проверить доступность серверов терминалов на c#

Tags: c#, tcp

Задача: на компьютере при запуске удаленного приложения проверять доступность сервера удаленных приложений и если проверка успешна осуществлять запуск приложения.
Самый простой способ отправлять эхо запрос на удаленный сервер. Но данный способ не самый лучший так как сервер или сервис может зависнуть или вообще в брандмауэре может быть запрещен эхо запрос. Ставить свое приложение для открытия сокета на сервер терминалов не вариант.

Подскажите как можно проверить доступность сервера по порту (в данном случае 3389)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты в любом случае можешь попробовать подключиться к серверу, код ошибки будет содержать причину, по которой ты не смог подключиться (например, если удаленный хост не отвечает на запрос (хост не доступен или неправильно указан адресс) или удаленная машина отвергнула запрос на подключение. Т.е по контексту ошибки технически можно предположить причину, почему машина отказала в соединении. Можно даже завести для этого отдельный асинхронный сокет, который будет постоянно опрашивать удаленную систему и корректировать логику работы основного приложения. Я когда то похожую задачу решил тем, что заюзал состояния, в случае если удаленная машина отвергла запрос на подключение, я просто пытаюсь выполнить подключение заново через определенный интервал времени и пишу в лог. Если кол-во ошибочных подключений было больше числа n, выполнял переподключение на резервные адреса. Собственно вся система была асинхронной, по этому разрешать ошибки было легко.

Comment: Как это можно реализовать на c#?

Comment: Ну смотри, например можешь создать объект класса tcpclient, и выполнять асинхронное подключение к серверу (в таком случае ты не блокируешь основной поток работы программы). Если подключение удалось ставишь состояние connected, и работаешь с системой, при этом мониторишь результаты выполнения операций send,recv. Если они завершились с ошибкой, в которой сообщается что удаленный хост не отвечает, изменяшь состояние на disconnected, при этом программа пытается выполнить подключение заново и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

собственно вот рабочий код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Создаем новый экземпляр TcpClient
            TcpClient newClient = new TcpClient();

            // Устанавливаем соединение с IPEndPoint
            IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse("10.50.0.9");
            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 3389);

            // Соединяемся с хостом
            newClient.Connect(endPoint);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString()); ;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: В общем да, но тебе нужно будет еще добавить асинхронное подключение и обработчики для send,recv, прямо почитай лучше async tcpclient example.